# How to call a variable defined in a function?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a module that is running calculations of demand for a panelboard. The function created exports a value for demand. I am trying to pull values that were defined in the calculation. For example the value that is assigned to totalrecep how would I be able to call that in another sub?

I want to be able to call some of the values that are defined in the demand function.

```
    Function Demand(myRange As Range)

    Application.Volatile   ' this causes the sheet to automatically update

    Dim LoadtypeA, LoadtypeB, LoadtypeC, Load1 As Excel.Range  'defines the ranges

    Dim newdemand As Double
    totalrecep = 0
    totaldemand = 0
    motordemanda = 0
    recepdemanda = 0
    Contdemanda = 0
    otherdemanda = 0
    motordemandb = 0
    recepdemandb = 0
    Contdemandb = 0
    otherdemandb = 0
    motordemandc = 0
    recepdemandc = 0
    Contdemandc = 0
    otherdemandc = 0
    motorMAX = 0
    cont25 = 0
    motor25 = 0
    recepdeduct = 0
    Poles = 84
    '===========================================================================================
    'This is for the first section of the panel
    '===========================================================================================


    'Set Load1 = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("F7:F48") 'gets the range
    Set Load1 = myRange

    'This is for the left side of the panel

    For x = 1 To (Poles / 2)

    LoadtypeA = Load1(x)
    LoadtypeB = Load1(x + 1)
    LoadtypeC = Load1(x + 2)

    'MsgBox Loadtype
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Select Case LoadtypeA
            
    Case "R"
    'MsgBox "R"
    recepdemanda = recepdemanda + Load1(x, 2)

    Case "M"
    'MsgBox "m"
    motordemanda = motordemanda + Load1(x, 2)

    If Load1(x, 2) > motorMAXa Then

    motorMAXa = Load1(x, 2)

    End If

    Case "C"
    'MsgBox "C"
    Contdemanda = Contdemanda + Load1(x, 2)

    Case "N"
    'MsgBox "N"
    otherdemanda = otherdemanda + Load1(x, 2)

    End Select

    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Select Case LoadtypeB
            
    Case "R"
    'MsgBox "R"
    recepdemandb = recepdemandb + Load1(x + 1, 2)

    Case "M"
    'MsgBox "M"
    motordemandb = motordemandb + Load1(x + 1, 2)

    If Load1(x + 1, 2) > motorMAXb Then

    motorMAXb = Load1(x + 1, 2)

    End If

    Case "C"
    'MsgBox "C"
    Contdemandb = Contdemandb + Load1(x + 1, 2)

    Case "N"
    'MsgBox "N"
    otherdemandb = otherdemandb + Load1(x + 1, 2)

    End Select
            
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
     Select Case LoadtypeC
            
    Case "R"
    'MsgBox "R"
    recepdemandc = recepdemandc + Load1(x + 2, 2)

    Case "M"
    'MsgBox "M"
    motordemandc = motordemandc + Load1(x + 2, 2)

    If Load1(x + 2, 2) > motorMAXc Then

    motorMAXc = Load1(x + 2, 2)

    End If

    Case "C"
    'MsgBox "C"
    Contdemandc = Contdemandc + Load1(x + 2, 2)

    Case "N"
    'MsgBox "N"
    otherdemandc = otherdemandc + Load1(x + 2, 2)

    End Select
            
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    x = x + 2
            
    Next x
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    ' End of Left side of panel
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Begin right side of panel

    For x = 1 To (Poles / 2)

    LoadtypeA = Load1(x, 11)
    LoadtypeB = Load1(x + 1, 11)
    LoadtypeC = Load1(x + 2, 11)

    'MsgBox Loadtype
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Select Case LoadtypeA
            
    Case "R"
    'MsgBox "R"
    recepdemanda = recepdemanda + Load1(x, 10)

    Case "M"
    'MsgBox "M"
    motordemanda = motordemanda + Load1(x, 10)

    If Load1(x, 10) > motorMAXa Then

    motorMAXa = Load1(x, 10)

    End If

    Case "C"
    'MsgBox "C"
    Contdemanda = Contdemanda + Load1(x, 10)
    Case "N"
    'MsgBox "N"
    otherdemanda = otherdemanda + Load1(x, 10)

    End Select

    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Select Case LoadtypeB
            
    Case "R"
    'MsgBox "R"
    recepdemandb = recepdemandb + Load1(x + 1, 10)

    Case "M"
    'MsgBox "M"
    motordemandb = motordemandb + Load1(x + 1, 10)

    If Load1(x + 1, 10) > motorMAXb Then

    motorMAXb = Load1(x + 1, 10)

    End If

    Case "C"
    'MsgBox "C"
    Contdemandb = Contdemandb + Load1(x + 1, 10)

    Case "N"
    'MsgBox "N"
    otherdemandb = otherdemandb + Load1(x + 1, 10)

    End Select
            
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
     Select Case LoadtypeC
            
    Case "R"
    'MsgBox "R"
    recepdemandc = recepdemandc + Load1(x + 2, 10)

    Case "M"
    'MsgBox "M"
    motordemandc = motordemandc + Load1(x + 2, 10)

    If Load1(x + 2, 10) > motorMAXc Then

    motorMAXc = Load1(x + 2, 10)

    End If

    Case "C"
    'MsgBox "C"
    Contdemandc = Contdemandc + Load1(x + 2, 10)

    Case "N"
    'MsgBox "N"
    otherdemandc = otherdemandc + Load1(x + 2, 10)

    End Select
            
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
            
    x = x + 2
            
    Next x

    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    ' End of Right side of panel
    ' Begin Demand Calcs
    ' Total Panel Calcs
    '----------------------------------------------------------------


    cont25 = (Contdemanda + Contdemandb + Contdemandc) * 0.25

    motor25 = (motorMAXa + motorMAXb + motorMAXc) * 0.25

    contdemand = Contdemanda + Contdemandb + Contdemandc
    motordemand = motordemanda + motordemandb + motordemandc
    totalrecep = recepdemanda + recepdemandb + recepdemandc
    otherdemand = otherdemanda + otherdemandb + otherdemandc
    If totalrecep > 10 Then

    recepdemand = ((totalrecep - 10) / 2 + 10)

    End If

    If totalrecep < 10 Then

    recepdemand = totalrecep

    End If

    newdemand = recepdemand + contdemand + motordemand + otherdemand + cont25 + motor25
    'newdemand = Load1(1)

    Demand = newdemand
    '----------------------------------------------------------------



    End Function
```

Comment: You could declare the variables at the top of the module (hence outside of the function definition). This will make them module-level variables whose values can be accessed anywhere in the module.

Comment: Or have the function return an array (probably a bad idea), or a custom class (probably a better idea).

Answer (score 0):

Create a public variable outside function and inside function
assigned your a public variable to local function variable.
then you can call a public variable from any place.

```
Option Explicit
Public x As String
Function myFun()
Dim name As String
name = "Hearno"
x = name
End Function
Sub Test()
Debug.Print x ' Hearno
End Sub
```